# beberlei DoctrineExtensions in ZF2 working fine on Windows localhost but shows fatal error Linux production server

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-extensions

I want to use use Day, Week, Month and Year functions of DoctrineExtensions in ZF2 and am getting the below error message. The code works fine on my local machine running on Windows but the same code does not work on server running on Linux.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day' not found
```

Here is my module.config.php configuration

```
'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'datetime_functions' => array(
                'day' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\Day',
                'week' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\Week',
                'month' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\Month',
                'Year' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\Year',
            ),
            'string_functions'   => array(),
        )
    ),
```

I installed the module using composer.

Comment: I recommend using Class name resolution via ::class (http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name), to reduce the amount of "magic" strings in your code and as a bonus, your IDE (if you use one) will hint if the class exists or not. `\DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\Day::class` instead of `'DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\Day'`.

Comment: Could you check in the vendor folder of your server, if the file containing the class exists? `find . -name "DoctrineExtensions*"` should tell you if it's the dependency is there.

Answer (score 0):

"DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\" should be "DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\" with small "s" not Capital "S". Linux are case sensitive that is why it cannot find the path of the classes. I have the same problem and this is how we solved it. Hope this helps.